# What are the default key bindings for Jet/Chopper for the XBox 360 controller

Tags: pc, battlefield-3

I recently started using an XBox 360 controller to fly jets, which has me crashing much much less.  I can even start to get kills with the guns!  Yay!

But I was wondering if there was somewhere I could look to see what all the buttons do by default.  In the options screen for the key bindings, the names used for the buttons don't really match up to the buttons on the controller.  So I'm not sure which buttons do what actions.

For example: (from [battlefield.wikia.com](http://battlefield.wikia.com/wiki/Key_binding))
[image]

The In Vehicle section, under joystick, lists "Fire Countermeasures" as button 6.  There is no button labeled as "Button 6" on the XBox controller.  Which button is it?  And all the other buttons...

Comment: Many games have different keybind pages for the controller and mouse/keyboard.  Does BF3, and are you looking at the right one?

Comment: Thanks Nick, I edited my question a bit to help clarify what I mean (hopefully).

Comment: I haven't been able to find this either - you could test it in-game and then reverse determine it. Seriously though, why are you using a controller on pc?

Comment: Only for the jets.  I still use KB/mouse for everything else.  Occasionally I use the controller for the helicopter - it's hard to tell if the controller is not as good as the keyboard, or if I am just inexperienced with it.  In contrast, as soon as I tried the controller with the jet, it was a eureka moment, it just felt better.

Answer (score 1):

It should be Right Bumper on the xbox 360, x for PC, and L1 for Ps3.  You have to have the countermeasures equipped though (IE: Flares, ECM, etc)

http://battlefield.wikia.com/wiki/IR_Flares